# comments_array filter doesn't work in some themes

Tags: comments

I have a problem with `comments_array`. The filter doesn't work in some themes.

```
add_filter( 'comments_array', array( $this, 'display_comment_image' ) ); // in __construct.

function display_comment_image( $comments ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        $comment->comment_content .= 'something';
    }
    return $comments;
}
```

Adding `var_dump($comments)` before return shows all added data, but this data doesn't appear in comments. This doesn't work only in some themes, in most of them it works.

Comment: Your code works correctly here. You code suggests that the filter is included in a class, are you initializing it? When and how?

Comment: Agreed with @cybmeta, we need context in order to understand what is going on. Most likely a priority thing, where your filter is ignored because of another filter in the themes in question. Review the doc for the $priority params: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: This class is a part of plugin. Initializing it calling static method get_instance(). It stops working only when activating some certain theme. I thought about priority but adding it to the filter doesn't Influence the result.

Comment: Then it seems a theme problem .... please add the code from the theme as well. Without code to reproduce the problem we can just try to guess but not truly help. Please, [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/215930/edit) and add all relevant information. The code already included in the question has not any problem at all.

Comment: Thank you for help, the problem was sold. Comments_array filter did not worked without html5. add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list', 'gallery', 'caption' ) ); helped with the current theme. Now it is the problem to add this filter in my plugin without editing the theme.